# How to mock SockJS in Karma/Jasmine unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, sockjs

I cannot find a way to mock the creation of `SockJS` class instance,

```
new SockJS(config.server);
```

when testing the function that contains it.

How do I go about it? How can I mock it, or at least - ignore it.